# Linq-to-Sql LEFT OUTER JOIN between 2 separate INNER JOINRS

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Trying to generate the following SQL from Linq-To-Sql

```
SELECT 
parenttableA.Name AS parentA,
childtableA.Name AS childA,
parenttableB.Name AS parentB,
childtableB.Name AS childB

FROM parenttableA
INNER JOIN childtableA ON childtableA.parentid = parenttableA.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(
parenttableB
INNER JOIN childtableB ON childtableB.parentid = parenttableB.id
)

ON parenttableB.townid = parenttableA.townid

WHERE parenttableA.townid = 123
```

This SQL should return something like:

```
parentA    childA    parentB    childB
=======    ======    =======    ======
John       Dave      Paul       Mark
Jim        John      (null)     (null)
```

So, in other words:

How can I have 2 separate inner joins linked together with a LEFT OUTER JOIN so that I still get "A" records from town 123, even if no "B" records exist for that town?

Comment: Perhaps my [LINQ to SQL Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for `IQueryable` for enumerable you should add null checks

```
var query = from ptA in parenttableA
            join ctA in childtableA on ptA.Id equals ctA.Id
            join ptBctB in (from ptB in parenttableB
                            join ctB in childtableB on ptB.Id equals ctB.Id
                            select new { ptB, ctB }) on ptA.TownId equals ptBctB.ptB.TownId into ptBGroup
            from ptBctBLeft in ptBGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ptA.TownId == 123
            select new
                   {
                       parentA = ptA.Name,
                       childA = ctA.Name,
                       parentB = ptBctBLeft.ptB.Name,
                       childB = ptBctBLeft.ctB.Name,
                   };
```

Also I think you can do this with just mapping configuration and have this as a property in your POCO but you need to post the EF config for that.

Comment: Many thanks, Filip.  I can now get the resultset I'm after.  Only thing I noticed was the generated SQL created a SELECT statement for the ptBGroup, whereas the SQL in my original message does not.  I wonder if the SELECT statement in the generated SQL impairs performance at all?

Comment: And thanks also for the variable names you've used.  ...Left, ...Group.  Helped a lot with understanding.

Comment: @NeilW I don't think it will have an impact on performance but I am not sure. You might want to run a profiler on the query if you want the max performance but I think query optimizer will handle this. If you have big issues with this I think you will need to run the raw sql but I don't think it will be needed.